# How adding a delete tab to property tabs in a property grid?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a delete tab to the tabs of a property grid. This tab should act like a button. When it is clicked it should fire an event an then be deselected.

Tabs added to the property grid acts different. They stays seletced until another tab is clicked.

Is there any way to configure a PropertyTab to act like a button?

```
public partial class PropertyGrid : Form
{
    public PropertyGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        propClass = new PropClass();
        pgrid_test.SelectedObject = propClass;
        pgrid_test.PropertyTabs.AddTabType(typeof(DeleteTab));
    }

    public class DeleteTab : PropertyTab
    {
        public override string TabName
        {
            get
            {
                return "delete attribute";
            }
        }
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object component, Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props;
            if (attributes == null)
            {
                props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(component);
            }
            else
            {
                props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(component, attributes);
            }
            return props;
        }

        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(object component, Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            return GetProperties(null, component, attributes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could handle the PropertyTabChanged event and switch back to the previous property tab. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.propertytabchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0